# Email address is not verified Amazon SES in Grails

Tags: grails, amazon-ses

I have configured Amazon SES but I can't send email. I get the error that the email isn't verified, but its impossible, because this email is running ok in another app that I have.

This is the error:

```
| Error com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.model.MessageRejectedException: Email address is not verified. (Service: AmazonSimpleEmailService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MessageRejected; Request ID: 6aab74bb-03c5-11e5-b255-e9ec5d4974cf)
| Error     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1160)
| Error     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:748)
| Error     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:467)
| Error     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:302)
| Error     at com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.invoke(AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.java:1443)
| Error     at com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.sendEmail(AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.java:1170)
| Error     at com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AmazonSimpleEmailService$sendEmail$2.call(Unknown Source)
| Error     at org.hscp.email.sender.plugin.SendEmailController.mail(SendEmailController.groovy:44)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.MixedGrailsControllerHelper.invoke(MixedGrailsControllerHelper.java:154)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleAction(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:375)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.executeAction(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:252)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:205)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:126)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsController.handleRequest(SimpleGrailsController.java:72)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet.doDispatch(GrailsDispatcherServlet.java:347)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
| Error     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
| Error     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
| Error     at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(UrlMappingUtils.java:178)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(UrlMappingUtils.java:144)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(UrlMappingUtils.java:135)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlMappingsFilter.java:216)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:69)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
| Error     at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
| Error     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
| Error     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
| Error     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
| Error     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
| Error     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
| Error     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
| Error 2015-05-26 17:36:54,191 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] ERROR plugin.SendEmailController  - null
```

This is my Controller.

```
def mail(){
    try{
        log.info "Sending email"
        String source = 'myEmail'
        Destination destination = new Destination(['YourEmail'])
        Content subject = new Content('test')
        Body body = new Body().withHtml(new Content('''Hi,<br />
        <br />
        Some <b>HTML</b> body…
        '''))
        Message message = new Message(subject, body)
        amazonWebService.ses.sendEmail(new SendEmailRequest(source, destination, message))
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        log.error e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

This is the plugin that I have installed: `runtime ':aws-sdk:1.9.37.1'`

And this is my Config.groovy when I add Amazon SES

```
environments {
    development {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
        grails.plugin.awssdk.accessKey = '....'
        grails.plugin.awssdk.secretKey = '....'
    }

    production {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = false
        grails.plugin.awssdk.accessKey = '...'
        grails.plugin.awssdk.secretKey = '...'
    }
}

grails.plugin.awssdk.region = 'eu-west-1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply call the verify action and then *immediately* use that email address expecting it to be verified.  All the verify action does is cause a verification email message with a unique link to be sent to the address in question, the recipient then must visit that link in order to complete the verification process before you can use the address with SES.

Comment: Yes, I know this. I add this that you tell me to don't display the error in the website. The problem is that this addres is verified. I use the same email addres in another app and work perfectly. I have to verify every time that I use one diferent web app?? I think it makes little sense

Comment: @Salva which address is it complaining about?  If your account has not been un-sandboxed then both the sender and recipient addresses or domains need to have been verified.

Comment: I just fix the problem. I have to add in the Config.groovy this lines: grails {
 plugin {
  awssdk {
   ses {
    region = 'us-east-1'
   }
  }
 }
   } And works, ok. Thanks Ian

Comment: @Salva ah yes, verifications are region-specific.